# Symfony URL organization

Tags: symfony, frameworks, navigation, symfony1, url-routing

A project I am working on contains a search feature. I would like users to have the ability to bookmark a page along with their query so they can bookmark their search page.

In the traditional implementation, I simply used GET parameters in the URL.

However, with symfony I am having a hard time understanding what is best to use for this functionality? is it just a matter of preference?

Should I just create a controller such as:

`search/{query}/{page}`

and when a user clicks on an option

`description/{id}`

or should I implement the traditional get variable in the URL:

Note the URL's on Stack Overflow, for example. When you search for something and you navigate the pages, the URL is something like:

`search?q="nav&page=2` But then when you click on a post the URL becomes something like `questions/19157969/expanded-navigation-by-default`, so it is kind of a mix of the two.

Couldn't SO use something like `search/search-term-here/2` for the same functionality? is there any benefit for picking GET over the alternative, using Symfony?

I appreciate any suggestions! many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of preference.  Some say that the URL is more important than the query string for SEO purposes. Also, /search/{query}/{page} is better looking in general, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Search terms can get very long.  Perhaps your searching mechanism is fairly simple, but personally I wouldn't want to make that assumption, especially if you plan on using the same feature for something in future you haven't designed the scale of yet.

Using a typical GET string is safe enough in my opinion, the controller should know what variables it needs, and GET queries generally don't (shouldn't) have an impact on routing.

However if you want to achieve pretty search URLs which can always be revisited, you could try storing each search in a database.

An example (untested):

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/search" name="search")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $search = new Search();
        $search->setQuery($request->query);
        // The query field would be of an object type in this example, 
        // but you could store the data any way you want really.

        // Add any additional information about the search/request to the entity.

        $em->persist($search);
        $em->flush();

        $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('search_results', array(
            'search_id' => $search->getId()
        )));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/search/{search_id}", name="search_results")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function resultsAction($search_id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if(! $search = $em->getRepository('AcmePostBundle:Search')) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }

        $query = $search->getQuery(); // This will be a ParameterBag

        // Run your search filters

        return array(
            // Your search results
        );
    }
}
```

In this example the request is to an action with a GET string as normal (could be POST if you prefer), which saves the search data and then redirects to an action which gets the search data from the database, does its filtering and show the results.

I can't see any real performance loss in a technique like this, the database queries to insert and select the search should be relatively small, but I can see the table in which you store them getting very full very quickly.

Then again it is always useful (occasionally) to draw reports on popular search terms.